# Not able to exit a for loop after element is dispalyed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to see if a particular element is displayed, then perform search for n times, else break loop, and continue with other actions in Selenium.

Once the row element is visible, the scripts stops instead of continuing with the code outside the loop.

```java
Boolean row = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'mytext')]")).isDisplayed();
        
if (row){
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        action.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
        Search.click();
        if (row == false){
            break;
        }
    }       
}
driver.findElement(By.xpath(something)).click();
```

Once row element is visible scripts stop instead of continuing with code outside the loop.

Comment: your code would never get into inner `if` because being inside a loop already means that `row == true` and it is no re-evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically issue is, You are using `.isDisplayed();` which works well if the web element is found. It will return yes. If the web element is not displayed, mostly you are going to get no such element exception.

Unfortunately, `.isDisplayed();` does not handle this exception effectively.

As a workaround, I would suggest using `findElements` which will return a list of web elements if found, else return an empty list.

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'mytext')]"));

if (rows.size() > 0){
    System.out.println("row is visible");
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        action.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
        Search.click();
        List<WebElement> rowsStatus = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'mytext')]"));
        if (rowsStatus.size() > 0 ) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(" exiting the loop if rows is found in for loop early");
            break;
        }
    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("Row is not visible, do something here to make it visible.");
}
driver.findElement(By.xpath(something)).click();
```

Comment: Where are we exiting the loop if rows is found in for loop early?

Comment: Please see above, I have updated the code. should get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this displaying function inside the `for` loop too. Only then the loop will be broken.

```java
// list of options which has more money
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  action.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
  Search.click();
  row = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'mytext')]")).isDisplayed();
  if (row == false){
    break;
  }
}
```